# How to use a tuple in an asp.net mvc view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tuples

I have the following controller:

```
 public class ModuleController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Modulo
        public ActionResult GetModules()
        {
            return PartialView(Module.GetModulesForUser(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().Name));
        }
    }
```

and this returns the modules for a user

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Gets the modules activated for a user
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>List of modules for the selected user</returns>
        public static Tuple<string, List<Modulo>> GetModulesForUser(string identityname)
        {
            // It needs to be cached for every user because every user can have different modules enabled.
            var cachekeyname = "ApplicationModulesPerUser|" + identityname;

            var cache = CacheConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
            Tuple<string, List<Modulo>> modulosPorUsuarioDeDirectorioActivo;

            //get object from cache
            string modulosUsuariosString = cache.StringGet(cachekeyname);
            //string modulosUsuariosString;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modulosUsuariosString))
            {
                modulosPorUsuarioDeDirectorioActivo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tuple<string, List<Modulo>>>(modulosUsuariosString);
                return modulosPorUsuarioDeDirectorioActivo;
            }

            var extPropLookupNameModulos = $"extension_{SettingsHelper.ClientId.Replace("-", "")}_{"Modulos"}";
            var client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
            var user = client.Users.GetByObjectId(identityname).ExecuteAsync().Result;
            var userFetcher = (User)user;
            var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
            var keyvaluepairModulos = userFetcher.GetExtendedProperties().FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.Key == extPropLookupNameModulos);
            var idsModulos = keyvaluepairModulos.Value.ToString().Split(',');
            var listaModulos= idsModulos.Select(idModulo => unitOfWork.ModuloRepository.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(idModulo))).ToList();
            modulosPorUsuarioDeDirectorioActivo = new Tuple<string, List<Modulo>> ( identityname, listaModulos);
            //convert object to json string
            modulosUsuariosString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modulosPorUsuarioDeDirectorioActivo);
            //save string in cache
            cache.StringSet(cachekeyname, modulosUsuariosString, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SettingsHelper.CacheModuleNames));
            return modulosPorUsuarioDeDirectorioActivo;
        }
```

However I need in the partial view to be able to access the Tuple and then render it.

```
model Tuple<string,List<xx.Models.GlobalAdmin.Models.Modulo>;

@foreach (var module in Model.Modules)
{
    <i class="fa @(@module.ClaseFontAwesome)" title="@module.Nombre"></i>
}
```

However I get this error:
[image: http://screencast.com/t/lMDg2IYc]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access to components of tuple by the `Item1`, ...`ItemN` properties.

Try this:

```
@foreach (var module in Model.Item2)
```

Comment: but the first line does not even compile ple<string,List<CapatechSaasApp.Models.GlobalAdmin.Models.Modulo>;

Comment: If this is not fixing your problem why is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

Tuple does not have a parameterless constructor which might be what's causing this issue. Why don't you create a single viewmodel that has a string and a list and pass it to the view?
 Ref [MVC Custom ViewModel and auto binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765406/mvc-custom-viewmodel-and-auto-binding)

Answer (score 2):

you can set the @model to be a dynamic object, and casting it to Tuple object.

```
@model dynamic 

 @{
   var result= model as Tuple<string,List<xx.Models.GlobalAdmin.Models.Modulo>;
 }
```